# Get screen output of a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am an absolute beginner with PLSQL and I'm stuck on that problem :

I have a function :

```
FUNCTION fn_easy RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'This is a simple function';
END fn_easy;
```

I would like in a simple SQL script to see this output, but this code :

```
set serveroutput on format wraped;

VAR retMsg VARCHAR2;

BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('=================================================');
  retMsg := pkg.fn_easy();
  dbms_output.put_line('=================================================');
END;

print retMsg;
```

Gives me the following error :

```
ORA-06550: Ligne 3, colonne 3 :
PLS-00201: identifier 'RETMSG' must be declared 
ORA-06550: Ligne 3, colonne 3 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: a) To reference bind variable you need to type colon `:` followed by the variable name, so in your PL/SQL block `retMsg` should become `:retMsg`; b) When you declare a bind variable of `varchar2` data type in SQL*PLUS and not specify its maximum  size, the size defaults to 1, so you'd better re-declare it making it large enough to store returned by the `fn_easy()` function value, otherwise you will hit `ORA-06502` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend the variable declaration in your anonymous block with DECLARE keyword. Also note that your 'print' should be also probably dbms_output.put_line and that it is outside the block (after the END keyword).

Answer (score 0):

This did the job :

```
DECLARE
retMsg VARCHAR2(100);

/* Appel de la procédure */
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('=================================================');
  dbms_output.put_line(agi_ws_pkg.fn_easy());
  dbms_output.put_line('=================================================');
END;
```

Comment: You can remove `retMsg` from your declaration part as you are not using it in you code.